# How to debug a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-studio

I'm a beginner that trying to build an health app for my school project

The program runs fine when I use Android 11 (API 30). The error happened when I use Android higher than 11 (API 30+).

The code where error happened:

```
private fun refreshMe(){
    val helper = profileHelper(applicationContext)
    val db = helper.readableDatabase
    val rs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM uProfile", null)

    rs.moveToLast()
    nama.text = rs.getString(1) //THE ERROR HAPPEN HERE
    umur.text = rs.getString(2)
    jk.text = rs.getString(3)
    data.text = rs.getString(4)
    kadarAu.text = rs.getString(5)
    kadarGd.text = rs.getString(6)
    kadarHb.text = rs.getString(7)
    kadarCh.text = rs.getString(8)
    kadarTdSis.text = rs.getString(9)
    kadarTdDia.text = rs.getString(10)
    rs.close()
    }
```

The error log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.lhsproj.labhealthpocket, PID: 10098
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lhsproj.labhealthpocket/com.lhsproj.labhealthpocket.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:521)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:53)
    at com.lhsproj.labhealthpocket.MainActivity.refreshMe(MainActivity.kt:63)
    at com.lhsproj.labhealthpocket.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:251)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

I've tried several solution from Stack Overflow earlier, but I found that they were difficult to implement in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **ALWAYS** check if a move (in your case `moveToLast`) was successful. All the `move????` methods return a Boolean, true if the move was successful or false if the move could not be made.

- -1 indicates a position that is **BEFORE THE FIRST ROW** and thus that the `moveToLastRow` **DID NOT MAKE THE MOVE**

***Additionally***

Hard coding cursor index values is typically not recommended. Instead it is recommended to typically use the Cursor's `getColumnIndex` or `getColumnIndexOrThrow` method to ascertain the index for a column and it's validity (-1 if invalid column name or IllegalArgumentException for a throw).

See [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor)

So you could have something along the lines of:-

```
private fun refreshMe(){
    val helper = profileHelper(applicationContext)
    val db = helper.readableDatabase
    val rs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM uProfile", null)

    val namaCI = rs.getColumnIndex("nama")
    val umrCI = rs.getColumnIndex("umur")
    val jkCI = rs.getColumnIndex("jk")
    val dataCI = rs.getColumnIndex("data")
    val kadarAuCI = rs.getColumnIndex("kadarAu")
    val kadarGdCI = rs.getColumnIndex("kadarGd")
    val kadarHbCI = rs.getColumnIndex("kadarHb")
    val kadarChCI = rs.getColumnIndex("kadaraCh")
    val kadarTdSisCI = rs.getColumnIndex("kadarTdSis")
    val kadarTdDiaCI = rs.getColumnIndex("kadarTdDia")
    val ok = namaCI >=0 && umrCI >= 0 && jkCI >= 0 && dataCI >0 && kadarAuCI >= 0 && kadarGdCI >= 0 && kadarHbCI >= 0 && kadarChCI >= 0 && kadarTdSisCI >= 0 && kadarTdDiaCI >= 0
    if (rs.moveToLast() && ok) {
        nama.text = rs.getString(namaCI) //THE ERROR HAPPEN HERE
        umur.text = rs.getString(umrCI)
        jk.text = rs.getString(jkCI)
        data.text = rs.getString(dataCI)
        kadarAu.text = rs.getString(kadarAuCI)
        kadarGd.text = rs.getString(kadarGdCI)
        kadarHb.text = rs.getString(kadarHbCI)
        kadarCh.text = rs.getString(kadarChCI)
        kadarTdSis.text = rs.getString(kadarTdSisCI)
        kadarTdDia.text = rs.getString(kadarTdDiaCI)
    } else {
        if (!ok) {
            /* INVALID COLUMN NAME */
        } else {
            /* NO DATA IN CURSOR */
        }
    }
    rs.close()
}
```

- ***column names have been guessed, so may not reflect the actual column names***

To debug you could add a BreakPoint e.g. on the line `rs.moveToLast()` and run in debug mode and then check the Cursor in the Debug Window or as an alternative use the `DatabaseUtils` `dumpCursor` method and inspect the log e.g. add the line `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(rs)` between lines `val rs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM uProfile", null)` and  `rs.moveToLast()`.

Comment: i see, in the link that you given its return -1 error because the column seems doesn't exist. please help me write the valid code or give me some example for my condition. i'll be really grateful

Comment: @LaluHabibSasiwimba recheck the answer, the -1 is the position of the cursor (before the first row). However, again see the answer re not using hard coded column indexes and code that may be suitable or the basis of improved code.

Comment: thanks for your helpp✨.. the app runs greatly thank you very much